# admin generator - list actions

Tags: symfony1, symfony-1.4

I am trying to create a list action in the admin generator.

I have the following in my `generator.yml` file:

```
 ......
  list:
    title: Sales
    actions: { _export: ~ }
    display: [=id, created_at]
```

So I have the `export` action in my `actions.class.php`

```
public function executeList_export(sfWebRequest $request)
{

}
```

And I have a template named: `List_exportSuccess.php`

The problem is, when I click the export link, I get: `Empty module and/or action after parsing the URL "/sales/List_export/action" (/).`

Am i naming these files/methods correctly?

Thanks

EDIT:
routing.yml

```
sales:
  class: sfDoctrineRouteCollection
  options:
    model:                sales
    module:               sales
    prefix_path:          /sales
    column:               id
    with_wildcard_routes: true

homepage:
  url:   /
  param: { module: dash, action: index }

sf_guard_signin:
  url:   /login
  param: { module: sfGuardAuth, action: signin }

sf_guard_signout:
  url:   /logout
  param: { module: sfGuardAuth, action: signout }

sf_guard_password:
  url:   /request_password
  param: { module: sfGuardAuth, action: password }
```

Comment: Can you paste your routing file?

Comment: samura - I have now updated my question to include my routing.yml file

Comment: Please post the complete routing (at least the ones not with class sfDoctrineRouteCollection)

Comment: samura - I have included my full routing.yml file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok. There's your problem. Add this to the very end of your routing.yml

```
default:
  url:   /:module/:action/*
```

or create a specific route for that action (which I don't recommend)

```
sales_export:
  url: /sales/List_export/action
  param: { module: sales, action: List_export }
```

Comment: Arghh! I knew it was something as simple as that. I deleted the contents of the routing file, i must have forgot to re-add the missing you one you spotted! Thank you